# Find table details in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having TEST schema and it has many tables.
I want to find table details like

```
Table name, column name, column datatype, column length, column default value, column allow null, column comment
```

I am using Oracle database, please guide me how to do this.
In SQL developer I am able to find these details for individual table but I want to get this for tables where table name starts with A,B or C (this can be any alphabet character)

Comment: It appears that you want the `dba_tab_columns` (or `all_tab_columns` or `user_tab_columns` depending on which tables you are looking at).

Comment: @JustinCave I want All table columns where table name starts with A,B or C and these tables belongs to TEST database.

Comment: "belongs to TEST database" is a bit confusing.  Is TEST a PDB inside a PDB?  If so, are you connected to TEST or to some other PDB?  Or are you using "database" in the sense many other database products do and you really mean that TEST is the Oracle schema name?  Again, most likely, you'd want one of the `*_tab_columns` views depending on things like who you're logging in as, what schema(s) you are interested in, and what privileges you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are logged in as a DBA user, you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   dba_tab_columns
WHERE  OWNER = 'TEST'
AND    SUBSTR(TABLE_NAME, 1, 1) IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'a', 'b', 'c');
```

Or you can query the `all_tab_columns` data dictionary view or, if you are logged in as the `TEST` user:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   user_tab_columns
WHERE  SUBSTR(TABLE_NAME, 1, 1) IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'a', 'b', 'c');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
where 
OWNER = 'TEST'
and SUBSTR(TABLE_NAME, 1, 1) IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'a', 'b', 'c');
```

this will give you column names and info of all tables accessible to the current user
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm